# SQL - "deleting" a row by setting all columns to NULL

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I'm new to .net.

I have a task at hand for my .net web project, using entity framework.

The task is: To delete a certain row in the db called `Products` using a webpage interface.
What I have right now: A webpage that displays all the rows in that db, with a button on the side for each row ( that doesn't have any logic behind it yet ), that is supposed to mean the `delete` button.

How I plan to delete the row: When the button is clicked, it should set all the contents of that row's columns to NULL and save it in the db.

The question is: Is that a viable solution for deleting a row? Could there be any problems in the future if I use that method for `deleting` the row? Are there maybe better solutions for that task?

Comment: Set all columns to NULL? Will be very confusing when many rows have been 'deleted'.

Comment: Why don't you simply delete the row?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: You won't be able to set the primary key to null. Just saying...

Comment: ... if there's one.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest that that you set , for instance  the **idProduct** to -1 (assuming that the id are always positive) since you don't want to delete it directly and Handel the db separately by using a trigger that launches when you update the **product** table

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_onUpdate_delete
ON product
AFTER UPDATE
AS
if (select idProduct from inserted) = -1
  begin
      DELETE FROM product WHERE id=(select idProduct from deleted)
   end
```

and please note that : **i assume that you are updating one row only every time**

Comment: '_i assume that you are updating one row only every time_' is a very dangerous assumption - which has caused lots of problems in various systems.